# Display names in a table below corresponding image-mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing a web application using asp.net mvc.I've a group of speakers under which I want to display the corresponding speaker Name. I've used array to retrieve the data .But it's not working with the other parameters.My view is :

```
@model  List<CTCFremont.View_Details> 

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Leaders";
}
<style>
    .img-circle {
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
</style>


<h2>Leaders</h2>
<div class ="container">
    <table>

    @{
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i+= 1)
        {
            j = i;

            <tr>
                @while (j <= i && j < Model.Count())
                {         
                    <td>
                        <img   src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model[j].Picture,0,Model[j].Picture.Length)" width="250" height="250" class="img-circle" />               
                    </td> 
                    j++;
                }
            </tr>  
            <tr> 
                @while (j <= i && j < Model.Count())
                {                                 
                    <td>              
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[j].Name)</b>                                              
                    </td> 
                    j++;
                }               
            </tr> 
            <tr>  
                @while (j <= i && j < Model.Count())
                {                                  
                    <td>                
                        <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[j].Position)</b>
                    </td> 
                    j++;
                }                   
            </tr>

            //foreach (var item in Model) {                    
            //   }
        }
    }
    </table>
</div>
```

My Model is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace CTCFremont.Controllers
{
    public class View_DetailsController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /View_Details/

        public ActionResult Gallery()
        {
            List<View_Details> all = new List<View_Details>();

            // Here MyDatabaseEntities is our datacontext
            using (CTCFremontEntities dc = new CTCFremontEntities())
            {
                all = dc.View_Details.ToList();
            }
            return View(all.ToList());
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? And what is the purpose of the `while` loops?

Comment: The code, as it is, displays just the images and does not display Name and Position, right?

Comment: Yes the code displays only images .but  I need to display names along with pictures. I've modified the code before pasting here . Help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are over complicating things with looping through the model multiple times.  Is this what you're trying to do?

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>    
        <td>
            <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(item.Picture,0,item.Picture.Length)" width="250" height="250" class="img-circle" />               
        </td> 
    </tr>  
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <b>@item.Name</b>
        </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr>  
        <td>                
            <b>@item.Position</b>
        </td> 
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Right - and the error message or exception or issue is.....?  You'll need to be a little clearer on exactly WHY/WHAT/HOW its not working.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 ..this is the error

Comment: Against which line of code?  Is your view model being populated correctly?  Are all the properties (`Name` and `Position`) being set correctly?

Comment: @foreach (var item in Model)

Comment: Clarify which action is being executed?  If `Model` is now null, it would have also been null in your original code.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue.